# How to repair Windows XP Network Connections when Dial-up displays "Unavailable - device missing"?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vpn

A Windows XP Professional SP3 machine has one **PPTP VPN connection** configured.

This VPN connection shows up under "Control Panel" > "Network Connections" > "Dial-up", with a subheading of "**Unavailable - device missing**".

I did already:

1. Download [devconn.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe) and copy it to c:\windows
2. Re-install the WAN miniport device drivers using:
3. `devcon.exe install c:\windows\inf\netrasa.inf MS_PppoeMiniport`
4. `devcon.exe install c:\windows\inf\netrasa.inf MS_NdisWanIp`
5. `devcon.exe install c:\windows\inf\netrasa.inf MS_PptpMiniport`
6. `devcon.exe install c:\windows\inf\netrasa.inf MS_L2tpMiniport`
7. reboot

Despite that "Dial-up" still shows "**Unavailable - device missing**" and "Device Manager" > "Network adapters" > "WAN Miniport (IP) #2" shows a yellow exclamation sign. The "General" tab of "WAN Miniport (IP) #2 Properties" displays:

> This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the
>   drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

The Driver File Details are:

- C:\WINDOWS\System32\DRIVERS\ndistapi.sys - 5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0852)
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\DRIVERS\ndiswan.sys - 5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-0852)

Both files exist at their respective path and file name locations.

How to repair Windows XP Network Connections when Dial-up displays "Unavailable - device missing"?

Comment: Does networking work otherwise?  What happens if you create a new PPTP VPN connector?

Comment: @techie007 Networking is ok. After creating a new PPTP VPN connection, a new icon shows up under "Dial-up" including a red cross and the text "Unavailable - device missing".